# Android - using json to pass non english characters,and getting it as question marks(???) to and from the server

Tags: php, android, sql, sql-server, json

What I'm trying to do is using json parser class in order to pass string to and from an sql database.

In order to do so, I'm using the next JsonParser class code to pass and get the strings value from and to the sql database -

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";


public JSONParser() {

}


public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {


    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);


        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;


        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }


        is.close();

        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }


    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }


    return jObj;

}


// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {


    try {


        if(method == "POST"){

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }


    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }


    return jObj;

}
}
```

Now it's working fine when it need to handle an english letters, but when I'm trying to pass a non english letters then it turns into question marks.

I can see the question marks at the Sql DB and also when I'm using the class to read results from the Sql I'm getting those question marks as results.

So I'm guessing that I'm missing something at JasonParser class when it sends data to the Sql.

Just to be sure that all other components are fine I'm adding codes that are involve in the sending info from the app to the server.

The next code is php for getting access to the DB -

```
  $username = "xxxxx"; 
$password = "xxxxx"; 
$host = "xxxxx"; 
$dbname = "xxxxxx"; 



$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 


try 
{ 

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 

    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 


$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 


if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
{ 
    function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array) 
    { 
        foreach($array as &$value) 
        { 
            if(is_array($value)) 
            { 
                undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $value = stripslashes($value); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST); 
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET); 
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE); 
} 


header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 


session_start();
```

The next code is how I set the Sql table -

```
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Index_2` (`username`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

As you can see I'm using in both codes the - utf8  - encoding - so that's why I'm thinking that something is missing at my JsonParser class in order to get it work fine.

So what am I missing here?

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Your InputStreamReader uses iso-8859-1 charset while your php script uses utf-8

Comment: Ok, so I've changed it to -  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8); - but still same problem

Comment: Can you try to open your php script in your browser to check what the output looks like. I'd say the chances are higher that there is something wrong on that side.

Comment: Well I've done two tests - the first one  , I went to the Sql table and entered manually a term with non english letters - and the app read it well, means when it reads the results from the server it can hamdle a non english words. Seconed test I used a form in the php file that handles data that comes from the app - so i fill a form with only non english letters - then i saw that the values gets fine into the sql table and also being shown well in the app when reading the result from the server - So the problem is at the JsonParser class for sure

Answer (score 3):

Well seems that I've solved it -

The line -

```
 httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
```

Should be -

```
 httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
```